# call a Python function from another function in PARALLEL

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

How can I call a function from a wrapper function in parallel without having to cease the following operations in the wrapper-function?

```
global mylist 
mylist = []

def log(mylist, i):
    for j in range(50):
        mylist.append(f'log_{i}_{j}')     
    
def wrapper(mylist, i):
    
    ## call log() in parallel so that the loop inside log and wrapper run in parallel 
    
    for _ in range(5):
        mylist.append(f'wrapper_{i}') 


for i in range(3):
    wrapper(mylist,i)
```

In the above example, I want to execute the loop inside log and wrapper in parallel.

Comment: You have to rebuild it for multiprocessing. In theory multithreading would work, but since CPython has a GIL it will just intersperse the operations. And you do so little work the overhead of just spawning threads (to say nothing of processes) is going to blow your runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Thread

global mylist
mylist = []

def log(mylist, i):
    for j in range(50):
        mylist.append(f'log_{i}_{j}')

def wrapper(mylist, i):

    Thread(target=log, args=[YOUR ARGS]).start()
    
    for _ in range(5):
        mylist.append(f'wrapper_{i}')
    
    
for i in range(3):
    wrapper(mylist,i)
```

Comment: Python thread-based code is a just illusion of concurrency ( never a true-[PARALLEL] code-execution ). GIL-lock monopolist simply re-[SERIAL]-ises the code-execution (thus principally avoiding concurrency at all, that was Guido's intent & CPython will remain so, seems, forever... ), so your proposal fails to meet the defined goal. Your proposed code is wrong in not meeting the defined property.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run `log()` in parallel you must start a separate thread. The easiest way to do is through the [threading API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) included in the standard Python library:

```
import threading

global mylist
mylist = []

def log(i):
    for j in range(50):
        mylist.append(f'log_{i}_{j}')   
    
def wrapper(mylist, i):

    t = threading.Thread(target=log, args=[i])
    t.start()
    
    for _ in range(5):
        mylist.append(f'wrapper_{i}')

    t.join()


for i in range(3):
    wrapper(mylist,i)
```

Note that you need to call the `join()` method so that your main program halts until the separate thread is done.

EDIT: This program works as-is due to the Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which prevents race conditions when appending to `mylist`. However, to modify the list elements themselves you would need to add some synchronization mechanism like a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects).

If your program is CPU bound, however, you might want to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threading, effectively using more than one CPU core (threading relies on the CPython interpreter switching between tasks, using just one actual thread). [Sharing global memory is harder though](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: I do not want my main function to wait for the thread to complete. The main function might call another wrapper function which in turn will create a new thread for log() without having to wait for the previous log call to complete. Does the flow happen according to what I just described?

Comment: Then you could just omit the join() call, since by default the main thread will not exit until there are no other threads running. The only exception, as far as I am aware, is when threads are spawned as daemons (not enabled by default).

Comment: Python thread-based code is a just illusion of concurrency ( never a true-[PARALLEL] code-execution ). GIL-lock monopolist simply re-[SERIAL]-ises the code-execution (thus principally avoiding concurrency at all, that was Guido's intent & CPython will remain so, seems, forever... ), so your proposal fails to meet the defined goal. Your proposed code is wrong in not meeting the defined property.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, yes, the way to do true parallel code execution is through the multiprocessing module, but that would require to refactor mostly everything to keep a mutable shared state. In the case of appending elements to a list, neither threading nor multiprocessing saves you any time. Depending on what tasks need to be performed in parallel (IO bound or CPU bound), one would use one of the two modules (and probably with a different technique than using a global list). It depends on the actual application.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want my main function to wait for the thread to complete.

in this case, you can use the main function as a thread launcher by passing a thread variable to it

```
from threading import Thread


global mylist
mylist = []

def log(mylist, i):

    for j in range(50):
        mylist.append(f'log_{i}_{j}')



def wrapper(mylist, i, t):

    t.start()

    for _ in range(5):
        mylist.append(f'wrapper_{i}')



for i in range(3):
    t = Thread(target=log, args=[mylist, i])
    wrapper(mylist,i,t)
```